# Mat-Checkbox is displayed as checked even when checked property is set to false

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following in component.html:

```
<mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="selectRow(row)"
      [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
```

in my component.ts I have:

```
public selection = new SelectionModel<any>(true, []);

public selectRow(row:any){
  if(this.isValid(row)){
     this.selection.toggle(row);
  }
}
```

if the row is not valid I do not want the checkbox to be checked. But even when my selection.selected-Array is empty and I am checking for `selection.isSelected(row)` in my template, the checkbox will be checked, after clicking on it.

Is there a workaround to prevent the checkbox from being checked, just by clicking on it, but rather rely on the return value it is receiving from `isSelected(row)`?

(This is the basic approach from the angular-material website. I couldn't finde any examples similar to what I am trying to do)

Comment: can you please create demo of this on codesandbox or jsfiddle or somewhere where it can be debugged easily?

Comment: If you do not want the checkbox to be clickable, you could just disable it.

Comment: @LeBavarois But I do want the user to click the checkbox. It should be something like this:

1. user clicks checkbox
2. validations are triggered --> Checkbox should be set back to not selected
3. checkbox is not selected (after show a dialog with information for the user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you

component.html

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="selectRow(row, $event)"></mat-checkbox>
```

component.ts

```
 public selectRow(event: MatCheckboxChange, row: any) {
   if (this.isValid(row)) {
      this.selection.toggle(row);
   } else {
      event.source.checked = false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually just found that out when I looked deeper into the angular material documentation and saw it is emitting an event of *MatCheckboxChange*. I was trying to do it with `event.target`.